# What does "ambush Prince Charming's wife" mean?

Tags: american-english, metaphors, cinema

In the 2014 film “The Other Woman”, there is an exchange between several characters

> **King Kate**: So what do I do now? So I'm, now I'm Barb Melman?      Barb Melman got divorced and now she has cheek implants and lives in a
>   condo in Norwalk and has to go on dates. I am not equipped to go on
>   dates. The last time I was single, I was 24 and the dating pool was
>   everyone. And now it's like a shallow puddle of age-appropriate men
>   who are old and gross and I don't want to do that.
>
> **Cameron Diaz**: I know that you think that it's that bad, but honestly, it's a lot worse. You know why? Because even if you meet a
>   nice guy... and when I mean "nice", I mean that he's, like, not an
>   obvious sociopath... you can't even actually get excited about it.
>
> You know why?  Because it's just a matter of time before someone gets
>   bored and unhappy and is saying that it's over, and that's a happy
>   ending. A shitty ending is that there's lying and cheating and you
>   ambush Prince Charming's wife.

---

What does Cameron Diaz mean by "*... and you ambush Prince Charming's wife.*"?

Comment: are we supposed to have watched the movie first or can you provide more context?

Comment: ok i give u more context

Comment: I don’t understand how this has anything to do with English. This is just like somebody saying something along the lines of (please excuse the cruddy Portuguese): *Há mentiras e enganos, e depois (tu) armas* (ou *você arma*) *uma emboscada contra a esposa do príncipe encantado*, and then you coming asking what they meant by this. It has nothing to do with language *per se*: you still have to identify the metaphors used to allude to the ambush and to Prince Charming. (I was surprised to find that *el famosísimo príncipe azul* from Spanish fairy tales has lost his blueness in Portuguese ones. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the hypothetical men King Kate would meet *Douglas* (also referred to as the prince charming).

According to Cameron Diaz the worst case scenario would be

**a.** King Kate has a relationship with Douglas

**b.** Douglas is married with another person

**c.** King Kate and Douglas get bored and unhappy

**d.** Instead of breaking up, they begin messing up with each other life (doing bad things to each other) that eventually get to Douglas wife ear (she hears about it one way or the other)

**e.** Douglas wife gets ambushed in this situation because she didn't do anything to deserve it and yet is in the middle of it all.

Comment: Please note: English is not my native language, so the simpler and clearer you can make your explanation, the better.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think Cameron Diaz's comment about "and then you ambush Prince Charming's wife", refers to the following scenario:

Cameron Diaz and Prince Charming have an affair. Cameron finds out about the wife only after the affair starts. Prince Charming attempts to keep up the affair without telling his wife. Cameron finally gets so angry at P.C. that *she* confronts his wife about the affair, just to let her know what kind of jerk she's married to. It is this confrontation that rates the description "you ambush Prince Charming's wife".

This is, as Cameron puts it, worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the meaning here (and I also have not watched the movie) is that at a certain age some of the men in the "pool" are married and you end up the other woman. Best case scenario, it doesn't last and one or both break it off and move on with their lives. The worst case scenario is the affair (and necessary lying) continue until he either leaves or someone else finds out and tells the wife who had no clue this was going on. Leaving her for the other woman is an ambush, and someone who finds out and outs the relationship to her is also an ambush. She was living her life either blissfully happy because he is that good of a liar, or she knows they are in a bad patch but believes in his fidelity and that they are working to a better place together.